# Debug eclipse plugin project -- PermGen space, out of memory error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a plugin project. When i debug this as an eclipse application, in the 2nd eclipse that opens, I want to open Project explorer window. As soon as I click on the button to do this, I get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space`. I tried changing the PermGen space in the preference, but it did not help. Can any one please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should add the `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m` or 512m to the `Window>Preferences>Java>Installed JREs` preference page.  Edit a JRE and add it to the Default VM arguments tab.

The eclipse native launcher uses the eclipse.ini to add extra permgen arguments to Oracle JVMs, but that information is not used during runtime launching.

Answer (score 4):

What if you try to extend the memory of eclipse when it starts. To do that simply open the .ini file (inside your eclipse folder) and edit the lines that refer to permSize and memory size:
e.g.

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=500m
-Xms500m
-Xmx2000m
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to set the permgen size for EVERY launch, you can also add the Parameter to the Debug Configuration.

```
Run > Debug Configurations
```

Choose the "Eclpise Application"-Configuration on the right side and choose `Arguments` in the Tabs.

Add `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m` to the VM arguments:

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -Xms256m -Xmx4g -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```