# Best practice in application design to avoid PermGen space failure

Tags: java

Are there any particular tips to design application immune to this type of error?
A reason of this error is frequent reload classes from perm space and JVM can't handle right collection of space where classes reside. However Tomcat 6 has such problem when Tomcat 7 doesn't. What is difference in design of Tomcat 7 to reload classes without generating the problem?

Comment: Tomcat 7 still does this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15523510/516433

Comment: Do you have any sources to back the claim it's gone in Tomcat 7? my opinion is this - hot deploy is always risking a perm gen error, and don't use Log4j, it seems to have some sort of relation :)

Comment: JRebel describes their approach to avoiding the permgen problem tomcat suffers from [here](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/resources/faq/#2).  In my experience, they do a pretty good job, but the extend `ClassLoader`s to do it...

Comment: What is causing the OOME: PermGen?

Answer (score 0):

In general, just up the permgen space. RAM is so cheap these days that you can afford to be generous with a 64bit JVM. However, this shouldn't happen that often once your code is in production and not subject to frequent redeployments.

Comment: I wish I could add more memory in Raspberry Pi